# What are the canonical references on wholesale credit risk management?

Tags: reference-request, credit-risk

I am trying to read up on "Wholesale credit risk ", but I can't find any useful references.

Why is the emphasis on wholesale?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious reason for emphasis on **wholesale** credit risk is because the term "wholesale" is linked to the Basel model taxonomy.

According to Basel Accord type capital adequacy standards, a bank must group its exposures into four categories to calculate credit risk-weighted assets. The **[Federal Reserve lists those categories](http://www.federalreserve.gov/generalinfo/basel2/draftnpr/npr/section_5.htm)** as wholesale, retail, securitization and equity.